# Twitter Rate Limits exploited by other user's third party app, even On twitter Native App? Bug or Feature?

Tags: android, twitter, messaging, mobile-application, rate-limiting

Seems like Today is real case of Monday blues. Yesterday The group I was part in twitter direct message have hour-long interesting discussion. And suddenly in morning 5 AM when I wake up I was not able to send the replies to messages I got.

[image]

Two questions:

1) Does twitter really impose rate limit of API calls on its own native APP?

2) if someone else involved in DM or in Time line conversation with me who is using some Third party app like electron or any of [this](https://www.androidheadlines.com/2019/02/best-third-party-twitter-applications-february-2019.html) can cause my rate limit exceed?

3) Lets Say, Today My manager assign me task of creating one Third party app for twitter. How to avoid this Rate Limit fiasco? for even a genuine user who is not using any third party app.

I believe this question comes under Stackoverflow. Kindly let me know if I need to move this to other stackexchange network site.

Disclaimer :  I am not using any third party app which access Twitter for my primary account. Not in my Desktop macOS, nor the Nokia android Device, iPad tablet, iPhone 6S,  Google Nexus I am holding right now. I do hold Developer account with twitter but thats not in use in weekends. And thats only accessed via console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter does have limits on DM or normal tweets. DMs are maximum 1000 per day and tweets are limited to 2400 per day. Posting to twitter could be from any App but limits will be observed.

[Here is twitter's guidelines.](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-limits)

Comment: Yes Thanks, I thought it would me much more, but outgoing DM is limited to 1000 only. Thats not fair but anyway tweets can be scheduled.